# Dictionary Syntax Error in Google Apps Script

Tags: dictionary, google-apps-script, syntax

I have a function that creates a dictionary based on a series of values from a sheet. I then try to pull one of the values from that sheet using a key. It works fine to log to the console. However, in an if statement, it says syntax error and nothing else. I cannot figure it out. Here is the function and the code that crashes. This problem only occurs in the for loop, and does not occur outside of it.

```
//creates dictionary
function columnLocationWithNotation(notation) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();
  var cells = data.getValues();
  var dictionary = {};

  switch (notation) {
    case "zeroIndex":
      for (var i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
        dictionary[cells[i][0]] = cells[i][1]  
      } 
      return dictionary
      break;
    case "regularIndex": 
      for (var i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
        dictionary[cells[i][0]] = cells[i][2]
      }
      return dictionary
      break;
    case "string": 
      for (var i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
        dictionary[cells[i][0]] = cells[i][3]
      }
      return dictionary
      break;             
  }
}

var master0indexDictionary = columnLocationWithNotation("zeroIndex")

for (var i = 1; i =< (sheet.getLastRow() - 1); i++) {
  var phone = master0indexDictionary["Tutor Name"]
  if (cells[i][phone] === phoneNumber) { //LINE WITH SYNTAX ERROR
    //do something

}
```

Comment: It seems that ``cells`` is not defined for the line of ``if (cells[i][phone] === phoneNumber) {``. ``cells`` defined in ``columnLocationWithNotation()`` cannot be used at outside of function. If ``cells`` is defined in the same scope with ``if (cells[i][phone] === phoneNumber) {``, can we as you about the error messages and the whole script without your private information?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the highlighted line that is causing the problem, even though there are many other issues with your script. There's no **'=<'** operator in JavaScript. Use **'<='** instead:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= (sheet.getLastRow() - 1); i++) {
```

Also, as Tanaike pointed out, your **'cells'** variable is only defined in the context of your **'columnLocationWithNotation(notation)'** function and will not be accessible from the global context. Globally-defined variables are visible from the functions you declare inside the global object, but not vice versa. Same applies to the **'sheet'** variable.  The **'phoneNumber'** variable doesn't seem to be defined, at least not in the snippet of code you provided.

Note that putting '**break'** after **'return'** statements is redundant.

```
 return dictionary;
      break;
```

You can just return out of **'switch'** statement without using breaks, or leave the breaks and put a single **'return'** statement after **'switch'**.

Finally, always put a semicolon at the end of the line. Doing so will help you avoid many potential pitfalls and issues with JS parser. I noticed several instances where you omitted the semicolon:

```
 return dictionary
      break;    

  var phone = master0indexDictionary["Tutor Name"]
```

For example, the following code will break if you don't have a habit of putting the semicolon in its rightful place

```
var a = {name: 'John'}  //no semicolon
[a].forEach(function(element) {
  Logger.log(element);    //logs undefined
  })
```

The JS parser treats this code as one line, so **'a'** will still be **'undefined'** by the time you call the **'forEach()'** loop on the array.